# Add dynamically hyperlink in listview column

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, hyperlink

I create a listview with code and i want the second column to contain a hyperlink which opens the default browser and loads the url.

i create listview like that:

```
GridView myGridView = new GridView();
myGridView.AllowsColumnReorder = false;

ListView l1 = new ListView();

GridViewColumn gvc0 = new GridViewColumn();
gvc0.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("AA");
gvc0.Header = "A/A";
gvc0.Width = 30;
myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc0);
GridViewColumn gvc1 = new GridViewColumn();
gvc1.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Description");
gvc1.Header = "Description";
gvc1.Width = 300;
myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc1);

l1.View = myGridView;
```

Also i fill the listview like that:

```
l1.Items.Add(new { AA = aa++, Description = descriptions});
```

I want the descriptions text to be a hyperlink. Is it posible?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to do the thing in XAML instead of this silly piece of code?

Comment: Maybe, but i have already wrote this 'silly piece of code'... If i don't found a solution i will try it with xaml. :-)

Comment: You should always try XAML before resorting to code. WPF is not winforms.

Answer (score 1):

In code-behind you can create `CellTemplate`:

```
GridView myGridView = new GridView();
myGridView.AllowsColumnReorder = false;

ListView l1 = new ListView();

GridViewColumn gvc0 = new GridViewColumn();
gvc0.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("AA");
gvc0.Header = "A/A";
gvc0.Width = 30;
myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc0);

GridViewColumn gvc1 = new GridViewColumn();
gvc1.Header = "Description";
gvc1.Width = 300;
FrameworkElementFactory fef = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
FrameworkElementFactory hyperlinkHolder = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Hyperlink));
hyperlinkHolder.SetBinding(Hyperlink.NavigateUriProperty, new Binding("Description"));
hyperlinkHolder.AddHandler(Hyperlink.RequestNavigateEvent, new RequestNavigateEventHandler(Hyperlink_RequestNavigate));
FrameworkElementFactory fef2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
Binding placeBinding = new Binding();
fef2.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, placeBinding);
placeBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Description");
hyperlinkHolder.AppendChild(fef2);
fef.AppendChild(hyperlinkHolder);
var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
dataTemplate.VisualTree = fef;
dataTemplate.DataType = typeof(ListViewItem);
gvc1.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;           
myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc1);

l1.View = myGridView;
```

Event handler:

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

You should use XAML to do that, it's more clear than first solution where all GUI you define in code-behind.

```
<ListView Name="l1">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="A/A" Width="30" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AA}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="300">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Description}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                </Hyperlink>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```